# GCM on android device and App crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

building a app that will push notification enabled.when i run it on real device app crashes on start let me show u guys my code.
MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import static com.my.app.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
import com.my.app.R;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private String TAG = "** pushAndroidActivity **";
        private TextView mDisplay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  "+regId);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
    mDisplay.setText("ffffff"+regId);
    }
```

and outside onCreate i have

```
private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
        if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(
        getString(R.string.error_config, name));
        }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
        }
```

but when i compile and run it on device app suddenly crashes before even loading MainActivity let me post LogCat here.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
 <receiver android:name=".MyC2dmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="com.my.app" />
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="com.my.app" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

Comment: Are you using Library project? If yes then must be sure that it is indicating with green mark. And if you are using jar file then it must be in **libs** folder. And finally all is perfect then clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273938/gcm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar

Comment: check: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273938/gcm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734303/gcm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055351/getting-noclassdeffounderror-with-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-on-nexus-4).

Comment: yess my gcm.jar isnt in libs. how can i copy it to libs?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to it unable to find the jar file. Have a look at the below solutions :

[GCM : java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273938/gcm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar)

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-gcmregistrar)

[GCM NoClassDefFoundError when checking device/manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456190/gcm-noclassdeffounderror-when-checking-device-manifest)

Comment: yess my GCM.jar is not in libs but how i am gona do that? i tried to copy but cant kindly tell me how can i do capy it to my libs folder?

Comment: Copy and paste it in Eclipse itself!

Comment: oh ya sorry. i did that but still crashes.

Comment: Try adding that jar to your classpath after pasting it under libs !

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat output, it is evident that Android couldn' t find **GCMRegistrar** class, which is either in library project, or in GCM.jar. In Android projects you need to put jar files inside libs folder, then they will automatically be included to your classpath. If you are using GCM.jar library, you need to copy it under libs folder. If libs folder does not exist, you can create it by right clicking on **project**.

Comment: i coppied gcm.jar to my libs folder and also added it to build path but still app crashes

Comment: Please view Manifest file and do let me know if i am missing somthing. Thanks

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) document explains everything in detail. It also contains [this](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client) client sample. You can check if your manifest and other parts right by looking the example.

Comment: ya i checked and everything looks fine. but app still crashes

Comment: i have downloaded and installed this example from google and this app does the same. means crashes before even start! what could be the reason now?? my phone? or anything else?

Comment: Have you updated google play services on the device? Can you test this program with a recent Android device? Check the logcat output to see if the error is the same class-not-found error.